# How do I use tklib widgets in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was looking for an IP address entry widget for tkinter for use with python3.7 and came across ipentry in the tklib.

https://core.tcl-lang.org/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tklib/files/modules/ipentry/ipentry.html#section2

This is not a terribly complicated need to 'recreate the wheel' for and there are several examples on stackoverflow for IP entry boxes but I'd really like to understand how to use the modules and widgets in the tklib with tkinter.  Documentation or examples appear to be few and far between.  Here's how far I've gotten:

First of all, I have to tell Python that this widget exists.

```
 import tkinter as tk
 root = tk.Tk()
 root.tk.call(‘package’,’require’,’ipentry’)
```

Then I created a class for the widget.

```
class iPentry(tk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Widget.__init__(self, master, '::ipentry::ipentry’)
```

Then I create an instance of it and pack it in my window.

```
enterIp = iPentry(root)
enterIp.pack()
```

So far so good.  I get a window with a familiar looking input box for an IPV4 address.
[image: example of ipentry widget]

The problem is that I haven't figured out how to use the get or complete or insert widget commands.  When I try to get from the enterIp widget that I created, I get an error.

```
myip = enterIp.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'iPentry' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I suspect that I'm missing some syntax concepts.  Any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `get()` function in your wrapper class `iPentry`:

```
def get(self):
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
```

Actually you need to define every functions that `ipentry` provides like above if you want to call them.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  I was able to implement this with ipentry but I can't seem to find the controlwidget widgets. tk.Widget.__init__(self, master, '::controlwidget::rdial') just throws an error : tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "::controlwidget::rdial".  I have TkVersion 8.5 installed. I think that all the controlwidgets are supposed to be in the standard library?

Comment: Did you just change `'::ipentry::ipentry'` to `'::controlwidget::rdial'` in your posted code?  You should change `root.tk.call('package','require','ipentry')` to `root.tk.call('package','require','controlwidget')` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `acw1668` I was able to work through some bone headed mistakes and figure this out a bit.  Here is some sample code for someone else who might like to work with these in Python.  They are pretty limited and I found a few things that didn't work even though they are documented on the lib page.  But they might be useful for some situations.  The rdial in particular was surprising because it is visually a "thumbwheel" rather than a typical round dial.  I have included a screenshot of what some of these look like in Macos.

This code displays an iPentry with a label below that will populate with the address when you press enter.  Then there is a bank of 3 sliders whose values will show in a label below. Then an rdial whose value shows in a label below and finally a "voltmeter" that bounces around based on a random number.  Enjoy.

[image: tklib controlwidgets]

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
# Python 3.7 and Tk version 8.6
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import random

class iPentry(tk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Widget.__init__(self, master, '::ipentry::ipentry')

    def get(self):
        return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')

    def complete(self):
        return self.tk.call(self._w, 'complete')

class CWslider(tk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, master, placeholder):
        tk.Widget.__init__(self, master, '::controlwidget::slider',
            {'variable':placeholder, 'from_':0, 'to':20, 'number':3,
            'width':55, 'background':'yellow'})

    def get(self):
        getvalue = self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
        getvalue = [int(x) for x in getvalue]
        return getvalue

    def set(self, value):
        self.tk.call(self._w, 'set', value)

    def complete(self):
        return self.tk.call(self._w, 'complete')

class CWrdial(tk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Widget.__init__(self, master, '::controlwidget::rdial',
            {'width':50, 'orient':'vertical', 'height':100,  'background':'green'})

    def get(self):
        return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')

    def complete(self):
        return self.tk.call(self._w, 'complete')


class CWvoltmeter(tk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, master, variable):
        tk.Widget.__init__(self, master, '::controlwidget::voltmeter',
            {'min':0, 'max':100, 'variable':variable})


def getIP(event):
    myip = enterIp.get()
    labelvar.set(myip)
    print(f"myip is {myip}")


def updating(master, myValuesvar, myvoltvar, interval):
    #we can't get value from placeholder because slider corrupts the IntVar?
    slidervalues = slider.get() #so we use the get method
    myValuesvar.set(slidervalues)
    mydialvalue.set(mydial.get())
    myvoltvar.set( random.randrange(0, 100, 1))
    root.after(interval, updating, root, myValuesvar, myvoltvar, interval)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x550+280+0")
root.tk.call('package','require','ipentry')
root.tk.call('package','require','controlwidget')

enterIp = iPentry(root)
enterIp.pack()
labelIP = tk.Label(root, text="Show The IP")
labelIP.pack()

labelvar = tk.StringVar()
label2 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=labelvar)
label2.pack()
root.bind('<Return>', getIP)

myvalues = [5,15,3]
myValuesvar = tk.IntVar()
placeholder = tk.IntVar() #necessary for slider to change values
slider = CWslider(root, placeholder)
slider.pack()
slider.set(myvalues)
labelSlider = tk.Label(root, textvariable=myValuesvar)
labelSlider.pack()

mydialvalue = tk.StringVar()
mydial = CWrdial(root)
mydial.pack()
labeldial = tk.Label(root, textvariable=mydialvalue)
labeldial.pack()

myvoltvar = tk.IntVar()
myvolt = CWvoltmeter(root, myvoltvar)
myvolt.pack()

interval = 300 #milliseconds for GUI
updating(root, myValuesvar, myvoltvar, interval)
root.mainloop()
sys.exit()
```